# Eigen difference between Vector, VectorX, VectorXi

Tags: arrays, vector, indexing, eigen

**Context**

I'm attempting to find the best one dimensional storage type for `int`. I am planning to use the Eigen::Vector objects as "index containers" (i.e. stores `int` values that represent indices of a larger Vector) and then do some custom validation of these "index containers" later on. While I may remove values out of this "index container", I will never add new ones to it: so `size` will always be <= `n`

However I have noticed that there are several different `Eigen::Vector` typedefs of which the documentation does not specify the differences. I can get a idea from the signature of the typedef, but largely am still unsure as to which one is appropriate.

1. `Eigen::Vector`
2. `Eigen::VectorX`
3. `Eigen::VectorXi`

Could someone please explain the key differences in these typedefs, I have some ideas as to which one means for example `VectorXi` the "i" represents `int`.

Edit

A example of what I mean by "index container" has been requested:

Imagine I have a boolean vector with values {true, false, true, true, false}

From this, my index container would have the values {0, 2, 3}

And the point of this question is to figure out the best kind of Eigen object for the index container

Edit 2

Unrelated, but why a index container?
I need to perform multiple different validation rules that are directly based on the index values.

E.g.
Validation 1: If any values in cont2 are smaller then cont1[0], remove them

```
cont1 cont2
--    --
0,    2,
5,    3,
10,   8,
13    12,

for (i = 0; i <= cont2.size(); i++)
    if cont2[i] <= cont1[0]:
       cont2.remove(i)
    else:
       break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no typdef `Eigen::Vector` or `Eigen::VectorX`. The format of such convenience typedefs is `Eigen::VectorNt`, where the possible choices for `N` and `t`are described in the [Eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html#title10):

> ## Convenience typedefs
>
> Eigen defines the following Matrix typedefs:
>
> ```
> MatrixNt for Matrix<type, N, N>. For example, MatrixXi for Matrix<int, Dynamic, Dynamic>.
> VectorNt for Matrix<type, N, 1>. For example, Vector2f for Matrix<float, 2, 1>.
> RowVectorNt for Matrix<type, 1, N>. For example, RowVector3d for Matrix<double, 1, 3>.
> ```
>
> Where:
>
> ```
> N can be any one of 2, 3, 4, or X (meaning Dynamic).
> t can be any one of i (meaning int), f (meaning float), d (meaning double), cf (meaning complex<float>), or cd (meaning complex<double>).
> ```

These are all variants of the dense `Eigen::Matrix` class.

It is not entirely clear what you mean with the "index container" that will refer to elements of a larger vector. The index numbers could be stored in an `Eigen::VectorXi` container, but there could be better options. If only those elements listed in the "index container" are required, and all other elements of the large vector are zero, then an [`Eigen::SparseVector`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html) would be useful. If you provide a specific example it will be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think to look in the Matrix section. An example would be where I store all the indices of a boolean vector that are true, e.g. {true, false, true} = {0, 2} (Index container).